# Iterating through a list of objects in an object of the same type

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make an object graph of webpages (edges being 'related' links between pages). Once I get this working I will create a dictionary of objects with the key as the URL so that I don't create multiple objects of the same page.

I have a class Page() and inside page is a list filled with objects of type Page(). I call the function root.crawlRelated() on my root page object. This populates the list. Then I try to iterate through the list and call obj.crawlRelated(). My goal is to then populate each object Page() in root.related[] with a list of their related pages.

On the website I am crawling each page has 5 related links, so after two generations there should be root with 5 objects in related and each of those objects should have 5 objects in their related. The problem I am having is that the crawlRelated() method is appending all of the objects to root rather then the respective objects in root.related.

```
from urllib import urlopen
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

####################CLASS PAGE######################
class Page():

    __title = ""
    __link = ""
    related = []
    __relatedURLs = []

    def __init__(self, title, link, relatedURLs):
        self.__title = title
        self.__link = link
        self.__relatedURLs = relatedURLs

    def get_attributes(self,key):
        return self.__attributes.get(key,None)

    def get_relatedURLs(self):
        return self.__relatedURLs

    def get_title(self):
        return self.__title

    def crawl(self,url):
        webpage = urlopen(url).read()
        patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
        patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel="canonical" href="([^"]*)" />')
        patFinderRelated = re.compile('<li><a href="([^"]*)"')

        findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle, webpage)
        findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink, webpage)
        findPatRelated = re.findall(patFinderRelated, webpage)

        self.related.append(Page(findPatTitle,findPatLink,findPatRelated))

    def crawlRelated(self):
        for link in self.__relatedURLs:
            self.crawl(link)
            print 'crawled related in', self.__title
####################END CLASS######################           


print 'doing some work...'
webpage = urlopen('http://medtwice.com/am-i-pregnant/').read()

patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel="canonical" href="([^"]*)" />')
patFinderRelated = re.compile('<li><a href="([^"]*)"')

findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle, webpage)
findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink, webpage)
findPatRelated = re.findall(patFinderRelated, webpage)

print 'found the webpage', findPatTitle

root = Page(findPatTitle,findPatLink,findPatRelated)
print 'Now crawling', root.get_relatedURLs()
root.crawlRelated()
print 'done crawling related'
print 'crawling related gen 2...'

i = 0
for rel in root.related:
    print 'crawling', rel#.get_title()
    #print rel.get_relatedURLs()
    rel.crawlRelated()
    i += 1
    if i > 3:
        break

print 'done crawling related gen 2'
print root.related
print len(root.related)
print len(root.related[0].related)
```

The if i > 3: break line is to prevent the infinite loop that happens due to this bug.

After this line of code runs

```
print len(root.related)
print len(root.related[0].related)
>> 25
>> 25
```

I want it to return

```
>>5
>>5
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in this section of your code:

```
class Page():

    __title = ""
    __link = ""
    related = []
    __relatedURLs = []

    def __init__(self, title, link, relatedURLs):
        self.__title = title
        self.__link = link
        self.__relatedURLs = relatedURLs
```

You've declared `related` as a class variable. That means all instances of the class `Page` share one array. Whether you access `root.related` or `rel.related` or so on, it's all the same array. So anything you add to, say, `rel.related` (in the `crawl` method) will also appear when you access `root.related`.

The solution is to make `related` an instance variable, by only assigning to it in the constructor. While you're at it, you should probably remove the other declarations of class variables because they get masked by the corresponding instance variables. Basically, start your class like this:

```
class Page():
    def __init__(self, title, link, relatedURLs):
        self.__title = title
        self.__link = link
        self.__relatedURLs = relatedURLs
        self.related = []
```